# laravel - get attribute from html tag

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, routes

So I have a form in my view:

```
{{Form::file('projectPicture', ['class' => 'uploadedImage', 'data-some-attribute' => ''])}}
```

with the attribute `data-some-attribute`.

And in my route I retrieve it like so:

```
$request->file('projectPicture');
```

How do I get a `data-some-attribute` in the route? Is it even possible?

I know I can use ajax to pass any data, but can it be avoided in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible how you intend it to work, only because it's not how form data is working under the hood. The second argument in your sample `Form::file` is just decorating the rendered form element. It has no correlation with the form data that is transferred between the server and client.

For all intents and purposes form data is just a glorified set of key value pairs. If you wanted to pass `some-data-attribute` to your route controller, you have two options -

1. Add another form field, and make it empty using [`Form::hidden`](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/157/creating-a-hidden-input-field). In this case, you would just name the field `some-data-attribute`.
2. If your form is submitted through a POST method, you can tack on `some-data-attribute` onto the form's route and retrieve it from the request.

   ie - `your/route` becomes `your/route?some-data-attribute=whatever`, and you can retrieve it later with something like `$request->input('some-data-attribute')`.

Comment: I see, seems like I'll have to redesign my architecture a little bit. Thank you, Austin.

Comment: No worries! The key takeaway with this is understanding that element attributes are purely front-end and useful only for the client (a browser). Form data is the exception to this, in that specific attributes on elements specify _what_ data to pass between the server and client, and _how_ to do it.